# WebSocket connection results in 404

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, websocket

I'm using the following code to establish

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7701/subscribe/ZS");

socket.onopen = function() {
    alert("Connection established!");
};
```

On a backend I have endpoint which accepts WS connections that have 'subscribe/**' pattern. When I try to test WS connection via Simple WebSocket Client, which is a chrome extension, everything works as expected. I've discovered that chrome sends the following request to the server:

```
Request URL:ws://localhost:7701/subscribe/ZS
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101
```

which is just what I expect.

However, when I run the code above, Chrome sends some strange request to the server:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:7701/?url=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7701%2Fsubscribe%2FZS&ubofix=f41665f3028c7fd10eecf573336216d3
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:7701
```

where there is url parameter which is `ws://localhost:7701/subscribe/ZS`.
Because of this server returns 404.

Could somebody give a hint - why Chrome sends a request like that? And is there any way just to send a request to "ws://localhost:7701/subscribe/ZS"?